# bluestack emulator eclipse can't run project

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary, emulation, bluestacks

i have bluestack as my emulator for eclipse, after installed, and run project in bluestack, and click installed project, nothing happened. but in my logcat haven't any error . 
The application project installed in bluestack can't run or take any effects

Comment: What about using an emulator like Genymotion or AVD?

Comment: i've tried both, avd can't run because google play application need update, and genymotion can work well but need more RAM space, so i moved to bluestack, because easy to use :D.